# Prevent Codeception from overriding Symfony classes

Tags: php, symfony, unit-testing, codeception

I'm writing some unit tests, and I've come across a problem because Codeception is using its own internal Symfony classes, rather than using the actual Symfony classes from my project. I haven't enabled Symfony as a module in my `codeception.yml` or `unit.suite.yml` files.

This seems like a design flaw in Codeception. The Symfony classes aren't set in stone, but by using Codeception, they're frozen, so the version of Symfony I'm using doesn't necessarily match when I'm running tests.

How can I use Symfony's own classes while running Codeception tests?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using a phar file or a global composer installation.
Version conflicts between local composer installation and phar or global installation is a quite common issue.

The only way to prevent it is to install Codeception as a local composer dependency, then it will use the same version of Symfony as your project.

Install: `composer require --dev codecept/codecept`.
Run: `./vendor/bin/codecept run`.

Comment: Does it still use its own classes, or Symfony's classes? I need to edit some Symfony classes and this project will never receive a Symfony update.

Comment: Do you mean components like symfony/console? If your modifications are installed using composer and are drop-in replacement for symfony components they will be used by Codeception too.

Comment: If I understand correctly, adding Codeception to Composer will load Symfony first, so its own classes will be in use.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I have created a wrapper around Codeception that loads the Symfony library before Codeception has a chance to load its own version. I don't like this solution as it is messy and not at all obvious as you have to call a different script instead of Codeception. However, it does work.